# C# Read web site xml file

Tags: c#, xml, import

I have one function which is

```
string fileToImport="C:\test.xml";
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileToImport);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

doc.Load(fileToImport);
```

This is point exact location of file.

But I want to use same function and import xml file from website.

For example I have below location.

```
http://testweb:1000/testdir/test.xml
```

Then I should open that location xml file and put in to the same way

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileToImport);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(fileToImport);
```

Anyone has best idea to get import this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader(client.DownloadString("http://testweb:1000/testdir/test.xml")))
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(reader);
    }
}
```

Also you can write this without WebClient&StringReader:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("http://testweb:1000/testdir/test.xml");
```

More at https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer actually I just found that we can directly use that function, XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("http://testweb:1000/testdir/test.xml")